# Jquery How to Fade in one by one in hover and fade Out One by one when mouse leave

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

look at the share button in this link
http://allure.elated-themes.com/taking-over-street-fashion-2/

i need a jquery code when mouse hover the share button, the share link fade in one by one and when the mouse leave fading in will stop and the visible links will fade out one by one.

here is my html code.

```
                                                <div class="item-share">
                                                    <span>Share</span>
                                                    <ul class="none gltr-med">
                                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="demo-icon icon-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="demo-icon icon-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="demo-icon icon-gplus"></i></a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not similar to your HTML code but it teaches you how to structure a fadeIn. If you want to make the images invisible at the beginning, set their opacity to 0 using CSS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
      var share = document.getElementById("share");
      share.onmouseover = function () {
        $("#facebook").fadeTo(200,1,function () {
          $("#twitter").fadeTo(200,1,function () {                                       $("#gplus").fadeTo(200,1); 
          });
        });
      }
    }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .button {
        opacity: 0;
        width:100px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: green;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="share" style="width:100px;height:50px;background-color:red">Hover Me</div>
        <div class="button" id="facebook">Facebook</div>
        <div class="button" id="twitter">Twitter</div>
        <div class="button" id="gplus">Gplus</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```